# How to write multiple conditions(Combination of and / or) in CASE statement?

Tags: sql, case

I am trying to select values based on the following case statment

```
CASE
when ty.type ='Catalog'
and zs.name='Aries'
or zs.name='Leo'
AND ( CASE 
when actual_finish_date is not null
then actual_finish_date
when updated_finish_date is not null
then updated_finish_date
else baseline_finish_date 
  END ) is not null
and visibility.ty_visibility !='Private'
then 1
else 0
END as PARTICIPANT,
```

Now the problem is it's not checking the entire condition,it's stopping at the first line itself(ty.type='Catalog').
Even when ty_visibility is equal to Private it's selecting the value as 1 instead of 0

Can someone point where I went wrong?

Comment: `ty.type ='Catalog'
and (zs.name='Aries'
or zs.name='Leo')`?

Comment: `coalesce(actual_finish_date , updated_finish_date , baseline_finish_date )`

Comment: Thanks..it works now!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @jarlh add an answer,so i can accept yours!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add parentheses to get 'Catalog' and one of the names:

```
ty.type ='Catalog' and (zs.name='Aries' or zs.name='Leo')
```

Or switch to IN:

```
ty.type ='Catalog' and zs.name IN ('Aries', 'Leo')
```

You can also use COALESCE to simplify the is not null tests:

```
coalesce(actual_finish_date , updated_finish_date , baseline_finish_date ) is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify or condition correctly. Hope following will work correct.

```
CASE
when ty.type ='Catalog'
and (zs.name='Aries'
or zs.name='Leo')
AND ( CASE 
when actual_finish_date is not null
then actual_finish_date
when updated_finish_date is not null
then updated_finish_date
else baseline_finish_date 
  END ) is not null
and visibility.ty_visibility !='Private'
then 1
else 0
END as PARTICIPANT,
```

Try this.